# How To Share Object Between multiple users

Tags: php, hash, yii2, project, multi-user

I've a doubt about a strange situation (not really strange but it needs to be managed).
I've a php app and a client ask for a specific development.
The specific development contains surveys and editable tables and it is divided in sections.

section1 -> surveys and tables

section2 -> surveys and tables etc...

Each section is heavy to load and i need to load it again only if it has been changed (by another user).

This is the major issue and i don't figure out how to manage this situation. (i was thinking to create some hash of each section and when the user try to open the session, compare this hash in order to know if are the same or not..if not load again the section). Do you have any better idea?

Comment: Add a log table who modified the data or keep track in the table by modified user and date.

Comment: add log table and get the last 2 entries for that record, if the `user_id` is same in both rows then it isnt changed, if not it is changed

Answer (score 1):

you can use optimistic lock mechanism to achieve this.

there is a quite nice solution in yii2, you can go to the documentation to check:
https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-db-baseactiverecord#optimisticLock()-detail

basically ActiveRecord has a build in feature for optimistic lock.

optimisticLock()

> Returns the name of the column that stores the lock version for implementing optimistic locking.

> Optimistic locking allows multiple users to access the same record for edits and avoids potential conflicts. In case when a user attempts to save the record upon some staled data (because another user has modified the data), a yii\db\StaleObjectException exception will be thrown, and the update or deletion is skipped.

> Optimistic locking is only supported by update() and delete().

If you use ActiveForm you could add OptimisticLockBehavior to your model class in order to automate the process.

https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-behaviors-optimisticlockbehavior

how it works:

> In the Web form that collects the user input, add a hidden field that stores the lock version of the recording being updated.

> To use this behavior, first enable optimistic lock by following the steps listed in optimisticLock(), remove the column name holding the lock version from the rules() method of your ActiveRecord class, then add the following code to it:

```
use yii\behaviors\OptimisticLockBehavior;

public function behaviors()
{
    return [
        OptimisticLockBehavior::class,
    ];
}
```

it is highly recommended to extend active record, only attach behaviour to child class. in this case parent class will be still usabel for it internall usage. (behaviour always try to check getBodyParams())

> OptimisticLockBehavior also provides a method named upgrade() that increases a model's version by one, that may be useful when you need to mark an entity as stale among connected clients and avoid any change to it until they load it again